# For algorithms such as the gossip protocol used by Cassandra, what is the advantage of random peer selection versus a deterministic approach?

Tags: algorithm, random, cassandra, protocols, deterministic

For algorithms such as the gossip protocol used by Cassandra, what is the advantage of random peer selection versus a deterministic approach such as iterating over the list of all peers?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077701/how-cassandra-select-the-node-to-send-request

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 That question is only related in that gossip is mentioned as a source of data. This question pertains to why the anti-entropy gossip implementation in Cassandra has uniform random peer selection versus a deterministic approach.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say it equalizes (statistically speaking) the time taken to detect failure for all peers in the list. If it were to iterate over a list of peers, then a failure in a peer that is near the tail of that list takes much longer to detect than one in a peer that's at the head of the list. I want to say something about better average case performance across the board, but I'm going to leave that to someone more experienced.