# what is the use of gossip protocol in apache cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, protocols, communication, p2p

I have problems understanding the utility of gossip protocol in Apache Cassandra (Why Cassandra use gossip protocol as a P2P communication protocol?)?

Given that Apache cassandra use gossip protocol, for wich reasons? is it just to exchange nodes states in cluster to find if a node is UP or DOWN? or it's used too to exchange node information like memory usage & disk capacity?

Comment: I answered something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077701/how-cassandra-select-the-node-to-send-request/

Comment: thank you, i want to know if it's possible to use gossip protocol in Cassandra to get node information (like memory usage). i know that i can get those information by using: ./nodetool info

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might want to read through this doc on the Gossip Architecture: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureGossip  It might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Gossip is used to broadcast members' state around the cluster. Part of the information exchanged:

- status
- health
- tokens
- schema version
- addresses
- data size

*Note: there might be other details that I have missed.* Another resource that you can consult is https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureGossip

Answer (score 0):

The Gossip protocol is the internal communication technique for nodes in a cluster to talk to each other. Gossip is an efficient, lightweight, reliable inter-nodal broadcast protocol for diffusing data. It's decentralized, "epidemic", fault tolerant and a peer-to-peer communication protocol. Cassandra uses gossiping for peer discovery and metadata propagation.